# How do I create a typescript object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My worker-api.ts file is:

```
   export class WorkerApi {

        private worker:Worker;

        constructor() {
            this.worker = new Worker("layout-worker.js");
        }
        // more ...
    }
```

And I am trying to create the in javascript as follows:

```
require(["../common/events.js", "worker-api.js"], function (events, worker) {
// worker is null so worker.WorkerApi() won't work either.
var api = new WorkerApi();
```

I also tried with internal modules so it was named MyModule.WorkerApi() - that also failed (we are using external modules for our .ts files).

What am I missing? I'm guessing I need to set something in the .ts file so the requires passes an object in function (events, worker) but can't find what it is.

thanks - dave

Comment: Have you tried looking at worker-api.js?

Comment: @SpiderPig Oh yes. When I did an internal module it created a global var MyModule - but that still was not available in the .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the .js file extension I.e.

```
require(["../common/events", "./worker-api"]
```